# Horizontal ScrollView with number of labels

Tags: ios

I need a horizontal ScrollView in my view,i have some words in array then i want to display those words on ScrollView,How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following code :

```
for (NSString *text in labelArray)
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,12,132,140)];
    imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollWidth +=165;
    label.text=text;
    [bookScroll addSubview:label];
}
```

Adjust the scroll width and bounds for label as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    for (NSString *text in wordsArray) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        label.text = text;
        [scrollView addSubview:label];

        labelFrame.origin.x +=labelFrame.size.width;
    }

    CGSize contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;
    contentSize.width = labelFrame.origin.x;
    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
```

Comment: but its printing only one word even i have 5 words in an array

Comment: @SwethaReddy Since I have given the width of label same as that of scrollView, only one label would be visible. You can modify the width of labelFrame and see if it's working. Meanwhile you can scroll and see other labels rite?

Comment: i asked how to display those strings too,im not getting how to place strings on scrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
int pos = 5;
for (int i=0; i<[yourArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILabel *lbl = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(pos, 0, 300, 440)];
            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([yourArray count]*320, 440)];
            pos = pos + 320;
        }
        else
        {
            [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(pos, 0, 748, 1004)];
            [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([yourArray count]*768, 1004)];
            pos = pos + 768;
        }        
        lbl.text = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"text"]];
        [_scrollView addSubview:lbl];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView), With some of the code modification, you can achieve what you want. Also, there is lot more to learn in that project.

At least, have a look at it.